# Facebook app request flow

Tags: javascript, facebook, request

Using the standard FB.ui apprequest stuff my app will send a request to a user. It will also return the request ID for me to save.

When the other user gets that request, if you hover over the link, you get to see the request IDs in the url. They look like this

```
https://apps.facebook.com/newsup-game/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=153603598154821&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_invite
```

But when they click on the link, it goes to the 'add this app' dialog as expected. Now the URL is this

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=294990753960629&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fapps.facebook.com%2Fnewsup-game&state=092385f0ea2b99808537b4970a4c84e8&scope=email%2Cpublish_actions%2Cuser_birthday%2Cuser_games_activity%2Cfriends_games_activity
```

When they finally click "play game", they are redirected back to the app where the URL is now this

```
https://apps.facebook.com/newsup-game/?state=092385f0ea2b99808537b4970a4c84e8&code=AQDEqV28lbF96g0tHeD9XjBjqzDFLpsF24jkJvh8LpaAynabRrfoiNu6DOtJv-Kyuc-TyCn32EeLpT2mATSCqKj9mnOQrdM6038OHXAayIfp67C3mO4uB2ZBUtuhn8lp-bjEfwF1EGtX_iZ8bBWlxbU2csL9doQtdlxQPgdFt-LDvkuG73CGnOW-YoVHrrWOOxXbVs0EjZNYGFWceOcZLS1i9ynubPBc4-r36agJfyznUNNJHDaJWA7TrJ6FvbOBDW5T9DwRHpBUdPTPkUo9Z-y74OIFTMXkYXyhexIo3suz9HtHn5ZhYUi1rHyomkUIbbU#_=_
```

So now the new user is back in my app, with 0 reference to the request. I am grabbing the request from the database and showing a list to the user, but I want them to be taking right into the game.  They can of course click the same notification again, and it will work this 2nd time.

So, how can I pass the request ID along in the URL when a new user accepts an app invite?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried saving it and passing it along in your redirect URL for authorizing the app?

Comment: Yea, facebook ignores it and throws this warning

when using FB.ui, you should not specify a redirect_uri.